# Display fonts in XNA with 3-dimensional coordinate primitives

Tags: fonts, 3d, xna-4.0, coordinate-systems

I am making a simulation with XNA 4.0.

We can display fonts but only with 2D coordinates, I need to display fonts with 3D coordinates. Please Help any technique how can i accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XNA 4.0, `SpriteBatch.Begin` can take any `Effect`. You can pass in a `BasicEffect` with an arbitrary set of transformation matrices (`World`, `View`, `Projection`) that will be used to transform your sprites, allowing you to "place" them in 3D space.

The "models" that `SpriteBatch` creates (basically a quad each sprite/letter) are the same size in units as the associated bitmap is in pixels.

Typically you'd treat the sprite plane as a model, and move it around using the `World` matrix.

The blog posts [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx) explain it in more detail.

Comment: very awesome game Dark. can you please help me how to learn this kind of lighting and shadows. its whats left in a solar system simulation i recently made